# how to change date format of database contents displayed by laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.7

this is my code :

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Article; 


class ArticleController extends Controller { 

    public function show($id){ 

        $article=Article::findOrfail($id); 

        return view('article', ['article' => $article]); 
    }

    public function list() {

        $articles=Article::all();

        return view('articles', ['articles'=>$articles]);
    } 

 }
```

and this is the date forming code but i don't know where to paste it, in my code:

date('d-m-Y', strtotime($articles->from_date));

Comment: Whatever file is the _article_ and _articles_ view.

Comment: articles is a table in data base and also i have php page called article.

Comment: You would use it in your view, but it would be on `$article` (a single object), not `$articles` (a collection of objects). However, you don't really need to use that code. If the from_date is a default date format, then you can add it to `protected $dates[];` in your model. It will then use the Carbon class, and you can use `$article->from_date->format('d-m-Y');`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.